# Create a dataframe with average lat,long coordinates for every US state

Tags: r

I want to create a dataframe in `R` with the mean latitude and mean longitude for every US state. My code. I cant find the proper data I guess.

```
# Load required libraries
library(ggplot2)

# Step 1: Use the state dataset from ggplot2, which contains state names, latitudes, and longitudes.
data("state")

# Step 2: Calculate the mean latitude and mean longitude for each state.
mean_state_data <- state %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  summarise(mean_latitude = mean(lat), mean_longitude = mean(long))

# Step 3: Create the new dataframe with the calculated mean values.
df_states <- data.frame(
  State = mean_state_data$region,
  Latitude = mean_state_data$mean_latitude,
  Longitude = mean_state_data$mean_longitude
)
```

Comment: is this dataset what you are after: `datasets::state.center` ?

Comment: can I have the name for each state as well?I do not know which coords belong to each state

Comment: all state information is stored in alphabetical order in the datasets package but here is code to name each vector: `lapply(datasets::state.center, function(x){setNames(x, state.abb)})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to calculate this yourself, you can easily obtain a shapefile of the US and use `st_centroid` to get the center points.

Here's a full reprex:

```r
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(tidyverse)

states <- ne_states(country = "United States of America", returnclass = "sf")

centers <- st_centroid(states) |> 
  st_coordinates() |> 
  as.data.frame() |>
  cbind(State = states$name)

centers <- centers[order(centers$State), c(3, 2, 1)]

head(centers)
#>         State        Y          X
#> 20    Alabama 32.77633  -86.83040
#> 17     Alaska 63.98522 -152.46031
#> 13    Arizona 34.27320 -111.65675
#> 48   Arkansas 34.89682  -92.44795
#> 14 California 37.17954 -119.46720
#> 38   Colorado 38.99774 -105.54669
```

And we can plot these co-ordinates over a map to ensure they are correct:

```r
ggplot(states) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_point(aes(X, Y), data = centers) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-180, -60)) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>